# Trying to identify a YA SF series

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult

I read these books sometime in the late 60s/early 70s in paperback in Ireland, so probably UK published. Short books,  not much more than a novella. I can remember reading 4 or 5 books in the series. I think one of the books was called "The Trouble with Trilobites" (but I can't find it on Google) and one took place in Wales. The titles were similar - The Trouble..., The Matter .. and may have been alliterative.

Unbenownst to all aliens have invaded and, disguised as humans, are plotting to take over. The hero (an American scientist or professional) discovers this by accident and, in the process, kills one or is involved in his dying. The body disintegrates as soon as the alien dies but the death is seen to occur and he is identified as the killer. He is then on the run (a) from the authorities who want to arrest him for murder and (b) the aliens who want to kill him because he knows they exist.

Each book takes place in a different part of the world. Following clues when he can, the hero travels around battling the aliens, all of whom (frustratingly) turn to dust when killed, so he can never prove anything. The plot is therefore a bit like The Fugitive (e.g. he meets a girl, but it cannot be). Don't know if he ever found a solution.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Trilobite&type=Fiction+Titles

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the Books relating to [**The Invaders**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112018/) tv series.

> The existence of the Invaders could not be documented by killing one and examining the body: when they died, their bodies would glow red and disintegrate along with their clothes and anything else they were touching, leaving little more than traces of black ash.

Movies & TV related [**Q&A**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59963/old-tv-series-about-red-people/59965#59965)

Ten books based on the television series were published.

[**Wikipedia Ref:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invaders#Books)

- Army of the Undead by Rafe Bernard (US, Pyramid Books, 1967) – the same story as  Halo Highway
- The Autumn Accelerator by Peter Leslie (UK, Corgi (a Transworld imprint), 1967)
- Enemies from Beyond by Keith Laumer (US, Pyramid Books, 1967)
- Halo Highway by Rafe Bernard (UK, Corgi, 1967) – the same story as Army of the Undead
- Invaders by Keith Laumer (US, Pyramid Books, 1967)
- Meteor Man by Keith Laumer (writing as Anthony Le Baron) (UK, Corgi, 1967)
- Dam of Death by Jack Pearl (US, Whitman (a Western Publishing imprint), 1967)
- The Invaders: Alien Missile Threat by Paul S. Newman (US, a Big Little Book from Whitman, 1967)
- **Night of the Trilobites** by Peter Leslie (UK, Corgi, 1969)
- The Invaders by Jim Rosin (US, Autumn Road Company, 2010)

Comment: That brings back memories... my grandmother bought me a copy of *Dam of Death* one CHristmas when I was a child. I hadn't realized it was a series.